# is it good way to store custom data in UserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, ios, caching, nsuserdefaults

i need to store some objects from table.
It will be no more than 100 objects.
Is it good way to store it like array in NSUserDefaults? Or there is any better way?

Comment: What kind of objects? While NSUserDefaults could handle it, I think that storing the information in a plist would be a bit of a cleaner approach if you are storing up to 100 objects.

Comment: Also, how are the objects related to each other?  If you are trying to save an object graph you could serialize it, save it, and later unarchive it when the app launches again.

Comment: Jeremy, could you tell me more about plist storing?

Comment: Alan, its the same class objects. Object contains about 4 string, 2 int and 3 array itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can store this is `NSUserDefaults` using `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"key"];` you probably shouldn't. Defaults was designed to store VERY small ammounts of data, like a users preferences (thus the name). If you wish to store more data than this, then you may want to look into `.plists`, `NSDocumentDirectory`, `Core-Data`, or `SQLite` databases.

Answer (score 2):

The better way would be to serialize it as a binary blob on disk using `NSArray`s `writeToFile:atomically:` or `writeToURL:atomically:`. `NSUserDefaults` aren't stored as binary and thus need extra parsing time upon loading, and extra time to write out to disk. `NSUserDefaults` is also not designed to hold large amounts of data but for a small set of settings data.

Comment: @EvgeniyS If you would look into the `NSArray` documentation, you would see that there are two init methods for reading from files `initWithContentsOfFile:`, `initWithContentsOfURL:` as well as two convenient methods: `arrayWithContentsOfFile:`, `arrayWithContentsOfURL:`

Comment: Heh.. sorry, ofcourse a should look it in docs.. Thx for your answer. I will read more about and after that i will accept your or the first answer.. :)

Comment: @EvgeniyS Haha, sorry, I didn't mean to sound rude! Depending on the kind of data you want to store and wether you want to run queries against it, NSPostWhenidle's answer might be the best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Store all custom data in NSDictionary or NSArray.

Now save dictionary or array with custom data in document directory follow  [this](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/read-and-write-array-dictionary-and-other-collections-to-files.html) link

Comment: its not exacly what im ask about.. You say how to manage data in application, but im ask how to cache data better way.. For you examle better to define custom object..

Answer (score -2):

no Storing data on NSUserDefaults  is not good, because it can cause a serious hack.

instead of it you can use  **AppDelegate** to store data globally.

Comment: Who said that the data was sensitive? I also don't see how the `AppDelegate` can help with persisting data.

Comment: you can store data till tour app is not forded closed. but if you want to pressing it than you can use plist.

Comment: AppDelegate is a good place to 'manage' data globally, but it does nothing for storing data between launches.

Comment: @SmartWork Then why did you suggest it if you agree that it didn't answer the OP's initial question.

Comment: @SmartWork So storing the data in plists because `NSUserDefaults` isn't secure? Seems about right.